# How can i link two Excel files in SharePoint?

Tags: excel, vba

I created two excel files. One as a template to fill and another to store the data from the first, written in VBA Code. 
Now I need to upload them to SharePoint so they can be used by everyone. But in the VBA code i need to tell where the WB is. 
How can i do it?

Comment: Sharepoint has changed in the past few years, so it may not work anymore, but here are some links - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/linking-two-excel-worksheets-in-sharepoint-online/cfe2741b-f09b-4d22-93ee-37218261a4d4?auth=1

Comment: https://support.geckoboard.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011099932-Connect-your-Excel-spreadsheet-via-Sharepoint